# how to disable writing without disabling the ckeditor toolbar?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

I need to disable only writing through ckeditor, but it can still be edited through the toolbar, such as bold, link, etc ...

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In Vue, you can use the following code:

```
editorConfig: {
    toolbar: [
        'heading', 
        '|', 
        'bold', 
        'italic', 
        'link', 
        'bulletedList',
        'numberedList', 
        'blockQuote'
    ],
}
```